# java: double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, class, method-chaining

This is the assignment:

> Implement a class Car. A Car object should have three (private) instance variables, one for fuel efficiency (representing miles per gallon), one for fuel level (representing gallons), and a variable that acts as an odometer (representing miles). The fuel efficiency of a car should be specified as a parameter in a Car constructor and the constructor should set the fuel level and the odometer to zero. There should also be a second Car constructor that has two parameters that initialize the fuel efficiency and the fuel level (and the constructor should set the odometer to zero). There should be getFuelEfficiency(), getOdometer(), and getFuelLevel() methods. There should be a method addFuel(double gallons) which adds a specified amount to the fuel level and then returns a reference to the current Car object. There should be a method drive(double miles) which simulates driving the car a specified distance. The drive() method should adjust the fuel level by the amount of fuel used, adjust the odometer by the amount of miles driven, and it should return the number of miles driven, which may be less than the number of miles specified if there is not enough fuel. Notice that there are no setFuelEfficiency(), setOdometer(), and setFuelLevel() methods. The fuel efficiency field is immutable; once it is set by the constructor, it cannot be changed. The odometer's value should only be changed by driving the car, as in a real car. The fuel level's value should only be changed by driving the car or by adding fuel. Here is a summary of the constructors and methods (the public interface) of the Car class.

This is my code:

```
public class Car {
    private double fuelEfficiency;
    private double fuelLevel;
    private double odometer;

    public Car(double fuelEfficiency) {
        this.fuelLevel = 0.0;
        this.odometer = 0.0;
    }

    public Car(double fuelEfficiency, double fuelLevel) {
        this.fuelLevel = fuelLevel;
        this.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency;
        this.odometer = 0.0;
    }

    public double getFuelEfficiency() {
        return this.fuelEfficiency;
    }

    public double getFuelLevel() {
        return this.fuelLevel;
    }

    public double getOdometer() {
        return this.odometer;
    }

    public double addFuel(double gallons) {
        this.fuelLevel = this.fuelLevel + gallons;
        return this.fuelLevel;
    }

    public double drive(double miles) {

        double distance = (this.fuelLevel * this.fuelEfficiency);

        if (distance > miles) {
            distance = miles;
        }

        this.fuelLevel = (fuelLevel - (distance / fuelEfficiency));
        this.odometer = odometer + distance;
        return distance;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "MPG: " + this.fuelEfficiency + "miles: " + this.odometer + "fuel: " + this.fuelLevel;
    }
}
```

This is the PreTestDrive that I am supposed to use to test my code and is not supposed to be changed:

```
public class PreTestDrive
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Car car1 = new Car(25.5);

      double fuelEfficiency = car1.getFuelEfficiency();
      double fuelLevel = car1.getFuelLevel();
      double odometer = car1.getOdometer();

      if (fuelLevel != 0.0 || fuelEfficiency != 25.5 || odometer != 0.0)
      {
         System.out.println("1. There is a problem with your constructors.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      Car car2 = new Car(10.0, 5.0);

      fuelEfficiency = car2.getFuelEfficiency();
      fuelLevel = car2.getFuelLevel();
      odometer = car2.getOdometer();

      if (fuelLevel != 5.0 || fuelEfficiency != 10.0 || odometer != 0.0)
      {
         System.out.println("2. There is a problem with your constructors.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      String s1 = car1.toString();

      if (! s1.equals("Car: mpg = 25.5, miles = 0.0, fuel = 0.0.") )
      {
         System.out.println("3. There is a problem with your toString() method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      String s2 = car2.toString();

      if (! s2.equals("Car: mpg = 10.0, miles = 0.0, fuel = 5.0.") )
      {
         System.out.println("4. There is a problem with your toString() method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      double newFuelLevel = car1.addFuel(12.5).getFuelLevel();

      fuelEfficiency = car1.getFuelEfficiency();
      odometer = car1.getOdometer();

      if(newFuelLevel != 12.5 || fuelEfficiency != 25.5 || odometer != 0.0)
      {
         System.out.println("5. There is a problem with your addFuel method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      double distance = car1.drive(76.5);

      if (distance != 76.5 || ! car1.toString().equals("Car: mpg = 25.5, miles = 76.5, fuel = 9.5."))
      {
         System.out.println("6. There is a problem with your drive method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      distance = car1.drive(1000);

      if (distance != 242.25 || ! car1.toString().equals("Car: mpg = 25.5, miles = 318.75, fuel = 0.0."))
      {
         System.out.println("7. There is a problem with your drive method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      distance = car1.drive(1);

      if (distance != 0.0 || ! car1.toString().equals("Car: mpg = 25.5, miles = 318.75, fuel = 0.0."))
      {
         System.out.println("8. There is a problem with your drive method.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      System.out.println("Your Car class passed all of these tests.");
   }
}
```

When I run the PreTestDrive, I get the error java: double cannot be dereferenced. Any ideas what it might be ?

Comment: Your `addFuel` method does not return what the instructions say it should return.

Comment: As khelwood indicates, it's this because your method returns a double, not an object reference: car1.addFuel(12.5).getFuelLevel();

Comment: Your code needs a lot of work. You create Car1 and then set 1 value.  Then you read 3 values back (2 of which are empty). Then the IF statement is invoked and your program will stop 100% of the time as a result of 2 values not bring set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There should be a method addFuel(double gallons) which adds a specified amount to the fuel level and then **returns a reference to the current Car object.**

Your `addFuel` method does not return a reference to the current Car object.

That would look like this:

```
public Car addFuel(double gallons) {
    this.fuelLevel += gallons;
    return this;
}
```

Also you're not setting the `fuelEfficiency` field in your `Car(double fuelEfficiency)` constructor.

Comment: I figured it out literally 3 minutes after I posted it, but thanks a lot!